# Camunda default directories to additional resources

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, camunda

I have just started to learn how to create forms with angularjs and while deploying it to camunda I faced with some problem. I am trying to create a form with tabs. And to include aditional html pages I use ng-include:

```
<div class="tab-content">
        <div ng-switch = "main.active.tab">
            <div ng-switch-when = 'persons'
                 ng-include = '"tabs/persons.html"'></div>
            <div ng-switch-when = 'history'
                 ng-include = '"tabs/history.html"'></div>
            <div ng-switch-when = 'deals'
                 ng-include = '"tabs/deals.html"'></div>
            <div ng-switch-when = 'products'
                 ng-include = '"tabs/products.html"'></div>
        </div>
</div>
```

But when I am deploying this form to camunda, there is an error: "404 Not Found - http: //localhost:8080/camunda/app/tasklist/default/tabs/persons.html". That's why I wonder how  I should write directories to make comunda upload html pages from my application's directory: "myapp/forms/tabs/persons.html"?

Thanks in advance